# Android Firebase Push Notification not received

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I followed the tutorial from this link http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-push-notification-example-using-firebase/ but I am not not receiving any notification on my device.

I checked and tried these links too, but could not find a solution 
[android - Firebase Notification Push Notification not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39120987/android-firebase-notification-push-notification-not-working)
[Push Notification not Received in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067859/push-notification-not-received-in-android)

In my firebase console, the notification sent is 0. Here is my androidManifest File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ather.healthapp">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WIFI" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.ather.healthapp.SignUpScreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity_New" />
    <activity android:name=".ActivityUserProfile" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" />
    <activity android:name=".TestActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".stDisplayListView" />
    <activity android:name=".DoctorAppointment" />
    <activity android:name=".todelete" />
    <activity android:name=".TestGoogleSignIn" />
    <activity android:name=".UserHistoryActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".UserMedicineAndTestActivity" />

    <service android:name="firebaseconnection.FirebaseIDService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name="firebaseconnection.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"

                />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".UserTestAndMedicine"></activity>
</application>
```

The gradle file is as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ather.healthapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':volley')
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
// this line must be included to integrate with Firebase
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Firebase Messaging Service file

```
package FirebaseConnection;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends      
com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

}

}
```

And the Firebase ID Service

```
package FirebaseConnection;

import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

/**
 * Persist token to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Can you share MyFirebaseMessageService and FirebaseIDService class code?

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: Do you have any `data` along with your notification? Please post the message you send as your notification.

Comment: There is no exception, and we are sending it though firebase console a simple hello message with no data

Comment: @rogerwar Added files as suggested.

Comment: did u created  [Firebase project](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1) and added the [config file](http://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592) to your app dir ?

Comment: also post your server side script code that you probaly calling from sendRegistrationToServer to send token to server, and notification trigger method in server side script to send push notification.

Comment: Same problem here sending from Firebase Console for testing. Any clues ?

Comment: I solved it by removing my firebase project, creating a GCM project and then convert it to FCM. Also don't forget to add the certificate SHA footprint

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is the name of your class!**

```
Manifest: MyFirebaseMessagingService

Service class: FirebaseMessagingService
```

the name of the two must be the same