# How do I check whether a specific notification channel is enabled in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using the following call to check whether notifications are enabled:

```java
NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext()).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

However, if a user disables only the channel, I cannot know about it.

How do I check whether a specific notification channel is enabled?

[image: Screenshot of Notifications screen in Settings]

Answer (score 66, accepted):

with backwards compatibility:

```
public boolean isNotificationChannelEnabled(Context context, @Nullable String channelId){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(channelId)) {
                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
                return channel.getImportance() != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE;
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();
        }
    }
```

Comment: A very minor thing, I prefer `""` [instead of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095501/is-stringutils-empty-recommended) `StringUtils.EMPTY_STRING`

Comment: `String channelId` should be `@Nullable` instead of `@NonNull` given that you might not use it for SDK < Oreo... Nullable works fine with `TextUtils.isEmpty()` as well

Comment: Instead of an empty string I would check for `channel != null`, because this could also be caused by a not empty but invalid channel id

Comment: `areNotificationsEnabled` should also be checked on Oreo+, because a channel could be enabled while the overall notifications are disabled

Comment: like @FlorianWalther said should also call areNotificationsEnabled(). like this `return (channel.getImportance() != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE) && NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();`

Comment: This is not working. I have disabled my app's channel and still receiving `IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT`

Comment: Is there perhaps a callback/listener for when the settings change of specific/all notification groups ? Maybe also the new notification permission?

Answer (score 34):

Check out the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#getImportance()).

> Users can modify the settings for notification channels, including
>   behaviors such as vibration and alert sound. You can call the
>   following two methods to discover the settings a user has applied to a
>   notification channel:
>
> To retrieve a single notification channel, you can call
>   `getNotificationChannel()`. To retrieve all notification channels
>   belonging to your app, you can call `getNotificationChannels()`. After
>   you have the `NotificationChannel`, you can use methods such as
>   `getVibrationPattern()` and `getSound()` to find out what settings the
>   user currently has. **To find out if a user blocked a notification
>   channel, you can call `getImportance()`. If the notification channel is
>   blocked, `getImportance()` returns `IMPORTANCE_NONE`**.

Comment: thansk. exacly what i need

Comment: Did Google remove that from their documentation? I can't find it anywhere. Is this still a reliable way to tell if your channel is disabled?

Comment: Seems to have moved https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationChannel#getImportance()

Comment: The note that `IMPORTANCE_NONE` means blocked (by the user) is not (anymore) in the linked docs.:-(

Comment: @Harald It has been moved to the section on the BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED notification

"Intent that is broadcast when a NotificationChannel is blocked (when `NotificationChannel#getImportance()` is `IMPORTANCE_NONE`)"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED

Answer (score 12):

Use this to check if either the notifications overall or the channels are disabled and bring the user to the corresponding settings:

In the calling method:

```
if (!notificationManager.areNotificationsEnabled()) {
        openNotificationSettings();
        return;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O &&
            isChannelBlocked(CHANNEL_1_ID)) {
        openChannelSettings(CHANNEL_1_ID);
        return;
    }
```

In your class:

```
private void openNotificationSettings() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
        intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@RequiresApi(26)
private boolean isChannelBlocked(String channelId) {
    NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);

    return channel != null &&
            channel.getImportance() == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE;
}

@RequiresApi(26)
private void openChannelSettings(String channelId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, channelId);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think example by @itzhar have one flaw: when user completely disabled notifications in app, we can get false positive (when channel itself wasn't disabled).

Updated code (in Kotlin) can look like:

```
fun isNotificationAllowed(context: Context): Boolean {
    return if (isOOrLater()) {
        areNotificationsEnabled(context) and isChannelDisabled(context)
    } else {
        areNotificationsEnabled(context)
    }
}

private fun areNotificationsEnabled(context: Context) =
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun isChannelDisabled(context: Context): Boolean{
    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    return channel.importance != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
}

private fun isOOrLater() = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O
```

Answer (score 3):

This method can help :

```
public boolean isNotificationChannelDisabled(@NonNull String channelId) {
        if(!channelId.equals(EMPTY)) {
            NotificationChannel channel = getManager().getNotificationChannel(channelId);
            return channel.getImportance() == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE;
        }

        return false;
    }

private NotificationManager getManager(@NonNull Context context) {
        return mManager(android.app.NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my full code:

```java
public static boolean isNotificationChannelEnabled(@NonNull String groupId, @NonNull String... channelIds) {
    boolean appNotificationEnable = NotificationManagerCompat.from(AppContext.getContext()).areNotificationsEnabled();
    if (!appNotificationEnable) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) AppContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            List<NotificationChannelGroup> groupList = manager.getNotificationChannelGroups();
            for (NotificationChannelGroup group : groupList) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(group.getId(), groupId)) {
                    if (group.isBlocked()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String channelId : channelIds) {
            NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
            if (channel != null && channel.getImportance() == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()) {
                for (String channelId : channelIds) {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(channelId)) {
                        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        if (manager != null) {
                            NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
                            if (channel.getImportance() == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }else return false;
        }else{
            return NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an implementation in Kotlin taking into account `areNotificationsEnabled` (For API level >= 26).

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun isNotificationChannelEnabled(channelId: String): Boolean {
    val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    return if (manager.areNotificationsEnabled()){
      val channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId)
      channel.importance != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
    } else false
  }
```