# FCM 404 "Requested entity was not found" errorCode: "UNREGISTERED"

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using `WebPush` in my project and it works well for the most part. However, occasionally - often after a prolonged period of use - a user will receive a 404 error with the following JSON response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What appears to be happening is that the token is expiring. The function `onTokenRefresh()` is cited on numerous occasions, but with little documentation on how to implement and certainly none regarding how to test. Some users have reported clearing cache will force a token refresh; this is not the case for me.

I have had this problem for nearly 6 months, and regularly check back to see if the documentation has improved, but there is no clear solution to this problem.

Any solutions to test at this point would be enormously appreciated. I am sure there are others out there using the under-documented `WebPush` notifications with similar issues.

Comment: Hi, did you get around this issue and how if yes please?  I'm experiencing similar and my suspicion is that the iOS system is not receiving the token from the payload.  In your case, using the WebPush, it would be that the WebPush system wasn't receiving the token.  Suggesting that there's an alternative way of writing the relevant payloads.

Answer (score 3):

`onTokenRefresh()` (now deprecated. Use `onNewToken(String s)` implementing `FirebaseMessagingService`, check out this other answer [FirebaseInstanceIdService is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51123197/firebaseinstanceidservice-is-deprecated)) is called every time the application installed gets a new token, whatever the reason it is (for instance, if the user goes to the "Applications" android configuration menu option, selects your application and press "Clear Data", but that is just one reason).

You have to use this method to call your backend and update the places where you stored the previous token, in order for your backend not to use it anymore to send any messages to it as it had been expired (and thus throwing the `NOT_FOUND`/`UNREGISTERED` error).

Don't forget to add the following in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as stated in the documentation:

> Include the following in the manifest:
>
> ```
> <service android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
>    </intent-filter>
> ```

Documentation of the new `FirebaseMessagingService`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error sending the notification from my server. The issue was that I just reinstalled the app because XCode wouldn't build it randomly, thus the FCM token had changed (I use it to specify my device as a test device) and the server was sending the old one in the push notification. So anybody in my case, just update the token on the server.